# SQL Script to Break up XML into Columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that stores audit history in an XML format.  Each document has its own history.  How can I parse out he XML data per document whereby each column in the XML represents and an actual column and action that took place in that column.

Example:

```html
<auditElement><field id="2881159" type="5" name="Responsiveness" formatstring=""><unSetChoice>2881167</unSetChoice><setChoice>2881166</setChoice></field></auditElement>
```

UnsetChoice and Set Choice are the columns.
Name=represents the action.

Answer (score 0):

Xml can be parsed using features such as [XQuery](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190262.aspx), or [OpenXml](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-za/library/ms186918.aspx).

Here's an example of xquery:

```
declare @xml as xml = '<auditElement><field id="2881159" type="5" name="Responsiveness"' +
                  ' formatstring=""><unSetChoice>2881167</unSetChoice>' + 
                  '<setChoice>2881166</setChoice></field></auditElement>';

SELECT
  Nodes.node.value('(field/@id)[1]', 'INT') AS FieldId,
  Nodes.node.value('(field/@name)[1]', 'varchar(50)') AS FieldName,
  Nodes.node.value('(field/unSetChoice/text())[1]', 'INT') AS OldValue,
  Nodes.node.value('(field/setChoice/text())[1]', 'INT') AS NewValue
FROM
  @xml.nodes('//auditElement') AS Nodes(node);
```

Result:

```
FieldId     FieldName                                          OldValue    NewValue
----------- -------------------------------------------------- ----------- -----------
2881159     Responsiveness                                     2881167     2881166
```

Comment: what if i had a table that stored multiple rows of the sample I gave.          Example: if there were 10 rows of xml data, how would i make the declaration read and output results?

Answer (score 0):

You can use OUTER APPLY and then break down the parts of the XML field.

The [value()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178030.aspx) method takes [XQuery](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xquery_intro.asp) expressions.

For example:

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (Id int identity(1,1) primary key, XmlCol1 xml);

insert into @T (XmlCol1) values 
('<auditElement><field id="2881159" type="5" name="Responsiveness" formatstring=""><unSetChoice>2881167</unSetChoice><setChoice>2881166</setChoice></field></auditElement>'),
('<auditElement><field id="2881160" type="6" name="Responsiveness" ><unSetChoice>2881187</unSetChoice><setChoice>2881188</setChoice></field></auditElement>');

select * 
from ( 
  select
   Id,
   a.field.value('@id', 'int') as xmlid,
   a.field.value('(unSetChoice)[1]', 'int') as unSetChoice,
   a.field.value('(setChoice)[1]', 'int') as setChoice,
   a.field.value('@type', 'int') as type,
   a.field.value('@name', 'varchar(max)') as name,
   a.field.value('@formatstring', 'varchar(max)') as formatstring
  from @T t
  outer apply t.XmlCol1.nodes('/auditElement/field') as a(field)
  where a.field.value('@id', 'int') > 0 and Id > 0
) q 
where name = 'Responsiveness';
```

Result:

```
Id  xmlid   unSetChoice setChoice   type    name            formatstring
1   2881159 2881167     2881166     5       Responsiveness
2   2881160 2881187     2881188     6       Responsiveness  NULL
```

Comment: This is on the right track, but how would I be able to read through a table that is distinct by different document ids that have xml data.  Meaning, without having to use a loop, is there a way to make a declaration to read off the table containing the rows of xml data per different document id and out put the data in the format you have shown.  Here is an example of the table that I created: CREATE TABLE #AuditHistoryForQuery(DocumentArtifactID INT, [Name] nvarchar(500), [HashValue] VARCHAR (100), [ActionString] nvarchar(100), [UserName] varchar(200), DetailsXML XML, [TimeStamp] datetime)

Comment: just add a where clause and select the rows you want from that temporary table as you normally would.  And if you want to select based on the xml extracted values, you can put the SQL in an subquery, and add a where clause to the outer query.

Comment: Btw, in the example I inserted 2 rows in the table. But it would get the same results if those 2 auditElement's would be in only 1 row. Ok, with 1 difference : the result would just have the same Id.

Comment: For the @T Table is it possible to have an entire table inserted and then have the xml script read through that table?

Comment: It's just a table variable used to test the syntax. Variables only exist in memory, and only exist while you run the code. But it's often usefull to just demonstrate sql.  So you can just replace @T in the select by that temporary table #AuditHistoryForQuery or another table.

Comment: Understood, what I forget to mention is that the XML data is located in a column by itself.  How would i reference the column and then break up the XML data from the column?

Comment: If it's about that DetailsXML column? That's also an XML type column. If it has XML data like `<bla><wha>x</<wha></bla>` then in the cross apply node search you would search for it like for example `//bla/wha` or just `/bla`.

Comment: You test out which xpath to use for the cross apply [here](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath)